# Python adding column to dataframe causes NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series and df

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,5])
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

When I add columns to df like this

```
df.loc[:, "0-2"] = s.iloc[0:3]
df.loc[:, "1-3"] = s.iloc[1:4]
```

I get df

```
   0-2  1-3
0    1  NaN
1    2  2.0
2    3  3.0
```

Why am I getting NaN? I tried create new series with correct idxs, but adding it to df still causes NaN.

What I want is

```
   0-2  1-3
0    1  2
1    2  3
2    3  5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try either of the following lines.

```
df.loc[:, "1-3"] = s.iloc[1:4].values
# -OR-
df.loc[:, "1-3"] = s.iloc[1:4].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Your original code is trying unsuccessfully to match the index of the data frame `df` to the index of the subset series `s.iloc[1:4]`. When it can't find the `0` index in the series, it places a `NaN` value in `df` at that location. You can get around this by only keeping the values so it doesn't try to match on the index or resetting the index on the subset series.

```
>>> s.iloc[1:4]
1    2
2    3
3    5
dtype: int64
```

Notice the index values since the original, unsubset series is the following.

```
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    5
dtype: int64
```

The index of the first row in `df` is 0. By dropping the indices with the `values` call, you bypass the index matching which is producing the `NaN`. By resetting the index in the second option, you make the indices the same.

Comment: So maybe I should reset indexes somehow?

Comment: Sure. You could use the following as well. `s.iloc[1:4].reset_index(drop=True)`