# How to add a pd.Series to a subset of multi-index DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-index dataframe created by:

```py
arrays = [['task_1','task_2', 'task_2'],['accuracy', 'accuracy', 'precision']]
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('task', 'metric'))
data = [[4., 5., 6.], [1., 1., 1.]]
res = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=mux, index=['total', 'counts']).transpose()

>>> res                  
                   total  counts
task   metric                  
task_1 accuracy     4.0     1.0
task_2 accuracy     5.0     1.0
       precision    6.0     1.0
```

Now I want to update the `total` column of `task_2` by adding `[0.1, 0.2]` to `task_2.accuracy` and `task_2.precision` respectively:

```py
update = pd.Series([0.1, 0.2], index=['accuracy', 'precision'])
res.total.task_2 += update

>>> res
                  total  counts
task   metric                  
task_1 accuracy     4.0     1.0
task_2 accuracy     NaN     1.0
       precision    NaN     1.0
```

Why I get `NaN`?
Learning from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041092/python-adding-column-to-dataframe-causes-nan), I also tried two ways attempting to match indices between `update` and `res.total.task_2`. However, neither of them worked in my case.

```
res.total.task_2 += update.values
# -OR-
res.total.task_2 += update.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

We have an option of adding on level, which we can use with `series.xs` to add only on the desired 0th level, then reindex and add:

```
res['total'] = (res['total'].xs("task_2",drop_level=False)
                .add(update,level=1).reindex(res.index)
                .fillna(res['total']))
print(res)

                  total  counts
task   metric                  
task_1 accuracy     4.0     1.0
task_2 accuracy     5.1     1.0
       precision    6.2     1.0
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I also saw your deleted post, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to change `res.total.task_2` value by updating all rows

```py
res.total.task_2.iloc[:] = res.total.task_2 + update
```

Or with [pandas.Series.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html)

```py
res.total.task_2.update(res.total.task_2 + update)
```

Or add value one by one

```py
for i in range(len(update)):
    res.total.task_2.iloc[i] += update.iloc[i]
```

```
# print(res)

                  total  counts
task   metric                  
task_1 accuracy     4.0     1.0
task_2 accuracy     5.1     1.0
       precision    6.2     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works. BTW, could you explain why the magical method `+=` fails in this case?

Comment: @YiweiJiang I guess the reason maybe by using `res.total.task_2 = ..`, it is creating new Series object rather than using the original Series.